# Ключевое слово this как поле в объекте, JS

Tags: javascript

Я знаю что ключевое слово this в методе объекта будет указывать на него, но почему this не работает вне метода? (Для полей например)

```js
let person = {
    name: "petro",
    surname: "torin",
    fullName: this.name + this.surname
}


console.log(person.fullName); //undefined
```

Пожалуста объясните почему это this в середине моего объекта указывает на объект window, и как сделать чтобы оно указывало на мой объект и записало в fullName мои name и surname.

Ответ: ключевое слово this относится к **вызывающему контексту**, а не к **объекту**.

Comment: `person.age` -> `person.fullName` ?

Comment: @Igor, исправил) это fullName

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043509/this-inside-object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @hindmost спасибо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что код `this.name + this.surname` выполняется, когда объекта `person` еще нет.

```js
let person = {
  name: "petro",
  surname: "torin",
  fullName: function() { return this.name + this.surname; }
};

console.log(person.fullName());
```