# Доступ к данным другой функции JS

Tags: javascript, ооп

Это пример из старого ООП в JS, здесь Developer наследуется от Human.

Объясните пожалуйста как Developer получает доступ к полю name в Human (догадываюсь что через метод apply(), но этот метод просто предназначен для выполнения функции в определенном контексте, как он позволяет Developer получить доступ к name ? )

```js
function Human(name) {
    this.name = name
}


function Developer(name, skills) {
    Human.apply(this,arguments)
    this.skill = skills
}


let petro = new Developer('bob','js');
console.log(petro.name); //bob
console.log(petro.skill); //js
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1143289/%d0%9a%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-this-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5-js

Comment: @Igor, не мог, не хватало репутации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта строчка

```
Human.apply(this,arguments)
```

то же самое, что

```
this.name = name
```

Код функции `Human` выполняется в контексте `this` конструктора `Developer`.